Client-Side 504 Gateway Timeout with EventSource and Vercel (Server Side Event)
I'm encountering a 504 Gateway Timeout error when using EventSource to connect to a Vercel Serverless function endpoint. The setup involves streaming data from MongoDB using change streams to clients. The code works flawlessly locally but encounters issues on Vercel.
It works fine in local but after deploying on vercel it does not work.
When deployed on Vercel, the EventSource connection intermittently returns a 504 Gateway Timeout error. This occurs despite setting appropriate timeout configurations and ensuring proper cleanup of EventSource connections on the client-side.
Server-Side
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  res.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.flushHeaders();

  let intervalId: NodeJS.Timeout;

  try {
    console.log("Change stream initialized");

    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const simulatedData = {
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        message: "This is a simulated message",
      };
      res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(simulatedData)}\n\n`);
      res.flush();
    }, 10000);

    req.on("close", () => {
      console.log("Client disconnected");
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      res.end();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error initializing change stream:", error);
    res.status(500).end();
  }
}

Client-Side
import { useEffect } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventSource = new EventSource(`/api/getdata`);

    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log('Received update:', data);
    };

    eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('EventSource error:', error);
      eventSource.close();
    };

    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
      console.log('EventSource closed');
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>Listening for updates...</div>;
}

